# How can i do push replacement using go router package in flutter [go router]

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the [go router](https://gorouter.dev/) plugin for my flutter web application, but I didn't find any way to do push replacement in navigation.

not only push replacement, can we do any other type of navigation link

- pushNamedAndRemoveUntil
- popUntil
  because these navigation options must be needed in kind of any system!

**What I tried**

- context.go(userStorage.redirectURL!);
- GoRouter.of(context).go(PagesCollection.adminDashboard);

they only pushed the next page, not replacing

**Note: I want this functionality in go router**

Answer (score 8):

In the latest `go_router`, You can use

1. [pushReplacement](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/GoRouter/pushReplacement.html) - `context.pushReplacement('/login');`

```
void pushReplacement(
  String location,
  {Object? extra}
)
```

2. [pushReplacementNamed](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/GoRouter/pushReplacementNamed.html) - `context.pushReplacementName(Routes.login)`
   (*Routes is a class having defination of login*)

```
void pushReplacementNamed(
  String name,
  {Map<String, String> params = const <String, String>{},
  Map<String, dynamic> queryParams = const <String, dynamic>{},
  Object? extra}
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
Router.neglect(context, () {
            context
                .goNamed('third', params: {"id": ID});
          });
```

It will neglect your current page. Hop this will helps you

Comment: Doesn't seem to work

Comment: can you provide a demo or code to show how this will work if we have page 1, page 2, and page 3.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a way ->

```
context.pop();
context.push(routeName);
```

Adding both these commands works similar to pushReplacement.

Comment: This is dangerous because it will throw an exception if there is only one element in the navigation stack

Comment: There are so many limitations with this library.. It only does well for managing web routes

Answer (score 3):

I am using go_router 6 and it works with:

```
context.pushReplacement()
```

Comment: if nested or shell route exist this will override it

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this;

```
while (context.canPop()) {
  context.pop();
}
context.pushReplacement(path, extra: data);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem before. Then this way worked for me
First you need to avoid nested routes:

```
    final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  routes: <GoRoute>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
          const OnboardingScreen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/login',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) => LoginScreen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/signup',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
          const SignupScreen(),
    ),
    
  ],
);
```

Use the above code instead of nesting like this:

```
 final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  routes: <GoRoute>[
    GoRoute(
      routes: <GoRoute>[
        GoRoute(
          path: 'login',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) => LoginScreen(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/signup',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
              const SignupScreen(),
        ),
      ],
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
          const OnboardingScreen(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

This will make you able to replace OnboardingScreen() from the above eg. So next you can use pushreplacement future with:

```
context.go("/routname");
```

or
GoRouter.of(context).go("/routname");
If u don't want replacement, then can just use:

```
context.push("/routname");
```

or

```
 GoRouter.of(context).push("/routname");
```

Comment: what about initialLocation ??

'/' wo't work

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) (`5.1.10`), you can use `GoRouter.of(context).replace('/your-route)` to do the same as `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(yourPage)`.

There is a [PR](https://github.com/flutter/packages/pull/2728) open to add `popUntil` but it looks like the flutter team doesn't want to support imperative routing methods and only focus on declarative routing (see, [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99112)).

It means [the `popUntil` PR](https://github.com/flutter/packages/pull/2728) might never be merged, and `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` never be supported.
It also means that `push` and `replace` might be removed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found from doc:

```
context.replace(location)
```

> Replaces the top-most page of the page stack with the given one but treats it as the same page.
> The page key will be reused. This will preserve the state and not run any page animation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use Sub-Route Redirects in Go Router.

Let's consider you want users to first go on your Homepage and then from there they tap Login, and go to Login page and then after Logging in, they go to Dashboard Page.

But when they press Browser's Back Button they should go to Homepage and not the LoginPage i.e skipping the LoginPage just like **"pushNameReplacement"**.

Then for this to happen you can configure redirects of each LoginPage and Dashboard page and get this functionality.

You can configure it such that whenever user (including from Browser's History) goes to Dashboard link it first checks if its Logged In then it opens otherwise it displays Login Page automatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

i use this functions and they are useful for me

```
void popUntil(String name){
  GoRouter router= AppRoutes.router;
  String currentRoute=router.location;
  while(router.canPop()&&name!=currentRoute){
    currentRoute=router.location;
    if(name!=currentRoute){
      router.pop();
    }
  }
}
```

```
void pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(String name){
  GoRouter router= AppRoutes.router;
  while(router.canPop()){
    router.pop();
  }
  router.replaceNamed(name);
}
```

work same as `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(route_name, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);`

any suggestion please drop a comment

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a nested or ShellRoute and want to avoid browser history to record the unnecessery navigation actions consider using neglect

```dart
onTap(){
    Router.neglect(context, () => context.go('/profile/security'));
}
```

Comment: can you provide a demo or code to show how this will work if we have page 1, page 2, and page 3.

Comment: No need. Above code behaves exactly as pushReplacement

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround that I did. I created an `extension` to `BuildContext`.

```dart
extension GoRouterContextX on BuildContext {
  void _doPop<T extends Object?>([T? result]) {
    if (Navigator.of(this).canPop()) {
      pop(result);
    }
  }

  /// Pop repeatedly until the specified location.
  ///
  /// If non-null, `result` will be used as the returned result.
  void popUntil<T extends Object?>(String location, [T? result]) {
    final routeInfo = GoRouter.of(this).routeInformationProvider;

    final routeMatches =
        (routeInfo.value.state as Map?)?['imperativeMatches'] as List<Map>;

    final routeLocations = routeMatches
        .map<String>((e) => e['location'])
        .toList()
        .reversed
        .toList();

    if (routeLocations.isEmpty) {
      _doPop<T>(result);
    }

    for (var routeLoc in routeLocations) {
      if (routeLoc != location) {
        _doPop<T>(result);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Use it like this:
`context.popUntil(route_path_here, true);`

> **Note:**
>
> At the time of this answer, I am using:
>
> - GoRouter 12.0.1
> - Flutter 3.13.9
> - Dart 3.1.5

Answer (score 0):

You can separately use route functions, for example if you want to use pushNamedAndRemoveUntil, you can try it adding by `onExit` function inside of your router.
I tried this:

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
 routes: [
   GoRoute(
     path: '/',
     builder: (context, state) => Container(),
   ),
   GoRoute(
     path: '/admin',
     builder: (context, state) => const Login(),
   ),
   GoRoute(
     path: '/admin/home',
     onExit: (_) => false,  <--- Added this line. This just terminate the operation
     builder: (context, state) => const Home(),
   ),
 ],
);
```

and so on. There are another functions available to use. The same with `redirect`. There is `redirect` argument function in `GoRouter` class. you can try it one by one