# Alternative to pushAndRemoveUntil in go router in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-go-router

Lets say I have navigation stack like

```
HomeScreen-> CartScreen -> OrderScreen -> AddressScreen -> ConfirmationScreen -> OrderSuccessScreen
```

Now i want to push a named route say `OrderSuccessScreen` when I am in `ConfirmationScreen`, and
remove all the previous route before `OrderSuccessScreen` and land directly to `HomeScreen`.

If I were to use `Navigator` I would go like:

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext context) => const OrderSuccessScreen()),
    ModalRoute.withName('/home'),
  );
```

How can i get it done using `go_router` ?

---

I see multiple github issues and reddit questions but no solution apparently:

1. [[go_router] .pushReplacement() and pushAndRemoveUntil() equivalent](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107052)
2. [[go_router] Add a equivalent to pushAndRemoveUntil()](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109128)
3. [What is the alternative of pushAndRemoveUntil on go_router package?](https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/vx61l0/what_is_the_alternative_of_pushandremoveuntil_on/)

Comment: Yes, I have seen those issues as well, but it seems that there is no equivalent to pushAndRemoveUntil in go_router package. However,  GoRouter.of(context).replace('/your-route') is the same as Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(yourPage). [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70547019/how-can-i-do-push-replacement-using-go-router-plugin-in-flutter-go-router)

Comment: did you found the ans i am also facing the same i can't able clear stack in go_router?

Answer (score 3):

There is no predefined method to do that with gorouter. What I use and works perfectly is while you canPop you call context.pop() then you push to your route

```
` 
   while (context.canPop()) { 
       context.pop();
   }
   context.push(Routes.addManuallyChargePointPage);
`
```

in this case we are popping until there is nothing. If yout want to pop until a specified route you can just check in your while the current route is different than your targeted one

```
` 
   while ((context.canPop())&&(ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.name != targetRoute)) { 
       context.pop();
   }
   context.push(Routes.addManuallyChargePointPage);
`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what seems to have worked for me. I admit it's kind of a hack.
Have a global GoRouter instance

```dart
GoRouter? globalGoRouter;

GoRouter getGoRouter() {
  return globalGoRouter ??= getRoutes();
}

GoRouter getRoutes() {
return GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/',
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const HomePage();
        },
        routes: <RouteBase>[
          GoRoute(
            name: 'auth',
            path: 'auth',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const AuthScreen();
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            name: 'login',
            path: 'login',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const LoginScreen();
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            name: 'landing',
            path: 'landing',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const LandingScreen();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
   );
}
```

```dart
void clearAndNavigate(String path) {
  while (getGoRouter().canPop() == true) {
    getGoRouter().pop();
  }
  getGoRouter().pushReplacement(path);
}
```

then you call the function

```dart
clearAndNavigate('login');
```

Open to suggestions for a less 'hacky' way

Answer (score 0):

```
while (GoRouter.of(context).canPop()) {
  GoRouter.of(context).pop();
}
context.pushReplacement(Routes.root.path);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**