# How to use pushAndRemoveUntil with go_router in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, dart, url-routing, flutter-go-router

I am using declarative routing package such as go_router in Flutter Web, and trying to achieve what pushAndRemoveUntil can do as it is really helpful in many scenarios.

I tried to achieve this with all possible ways but none of the thing worked out for me.

Comment: Maybe you can try alfiepoleon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76947606/19022913)

Comment: @FeyizOktayAydır no, I tried this.