# Flutter GoRouter how to pass multiple parameters

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

everyone. I'm new to `GoRouter`, and I'm looking for guidance for webApp on how to pass multiple parameters in GoRouter. I've seen many examples, but they all use strings, whereas I have parameters of type 'Function' and 'bool'.

Here's my class:

```
 class EditCustomerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function updateTab;
  final bool edit;

  const EditCustomerPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.updateTab,
    required this.edit,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditCustomerPageState createState() => _EditCustomerPageState();
}
```

Comment: There is an `extra` parameter in the `push` method where you can pass whatever you want and access it with `state.extra` in that route's builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define route as follows:

```
GoRoute(
      name: RouteName.EditCustomerPageRoute,
      path: '/EditCustomerPageRoute',
      builder: (context, state) { 
        final data = state.extra! as Map<String,dynamic>;
        return EditCustomerPage(updateTab: data["updateTab"],edit: data["edit"]);
      }
    ),
```

Call it as follows to navigate:

```
context.push(RouteName.EditCustomerPageRoute,extra: {"updateTab":updateTabValue,"edit":editValue);
```

Comment: thanks, @smita and can you please tell me the replacement of 'pushAndRemoveUntil' for goRouter/

Comment: @SyedRehan According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75873344/alternative-to-pushandremoveuntil-in-go-router-in-flutter  , there is no equivalent to pushAndRemoveUntil in go_router package.